# How to implement decorator on object oriented program in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Have a question on decorators. I am trying to understand the decorator concept in python but got stuck at the use of decorators in classes.
**with_class.py**

```
class decorate:
      def __init__(self,f):
          self.f = f

      def __call__(self)
          self.f()
@decorate
def foo():
    print "inside foo"
foo()
```

I put the whole code inside a single .py file and it executed as expected.
OUTPUT:  inside foo

But then I tried to create an object for the class decorate in another .py file and tried to execute to get the same output.
Commented the `foo()` in the first .py file and used the below code in the second .py file.

**use_class.py**

```
import with_class
a = with_class.decorate()
```

But it is throwing error `TypeError: __init__ takes exactly 2 arguments(1 given)`. It is expected as while calling the `__init__` we should provide 2 arguments. 
But am not getting what to pass for executing the method `foo` on the `use_class.py`.
Again I tried to use `__call__(self,f)` by removing `f` from `__init__` but it also gives error.
It seems I am not getting the concept.

Comment: If you had written `decorate` as a function, what argument would you have passed it? Pass it that argument.

Comment: Why are you calling `decorate`? You should call `with_class.foo()`.

Comment: decorate is the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What

```
@decorate
def foo():
    print "inside foo"
```

does is equivalent to

```
def foo():
    print "inside foo"

foo = decorate(foo)
```

So `foo` is the name that the decorated function (an object of class `decorate`, really) is bound to in the `with_class` module. From `use_class.py`, you should then do

```
import with_class

a = with_class.foo()
```

Comment: If I want to pass a parameter to the decorated function above can do like::  a = with_class.foo(x)  and accordingly modify the with_class.py                                                                                     class decorate:
      def __init__(self,f):
          self.f = f

      def __call__(self,x)
          self.f(x)
@decorate
def foo(x):
    print "inside foo" , x

Comment: Now if i want pass a function in place of x. I have functin defined  in with_class.py and in the use_class.py I want to pass to " a = with_class.foo(with_class.decorate.disp())" .  disp() is the function defined inside the class. The code within the with_class.py is modified to:       class decorate:
      def __init__(self,f):
          self.f = f
      def __call__(self,g)
          self.f(g)                                                                                      def  disp(self): print "inside the display"
@decorate
def foo(fn):
    print "inside foo"  fn()